# Why I can't streaming a live video from iOS app to Facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, streaming

I want to stream a live video from my iOS app in my news feed on Facebook. I have this permission for that: **publish_actions** and **user_videos**, according with FB documentation:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api. But when I use other accounts to login (not the one on which my application registered), I keep getting this error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 100;
        "fbtrace_id" = "Dx9+pqUfSB5";
        message = "(#100) No permission to perform current operation.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
```

Please help me solving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `not the one on which my application registered` means one on which fb app regiter or your app? your question is not much clear

Comment: The streaming works only if I enter my FB id and my application is also registered with my FB id. If I'm logging in with any other FB account in my app, then I receive the message mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: did you success to stream a video via your iOS app ? about your problem your FB app isn't published so only the users have roles in the app you can use their accounts.